# how to make arrays from txt file C

Tags: c, arrays, file, getc

I got text file with information: **(100;200;first)**.Can anybody tell me how to seperate this information into three arrays: **Min=100,Max=200 and Name=first**. I have tried this whith

**c=getc(inp);**

**i=atoi(szinput);**

but its read 10 for first time and 00 for second... and so on in loop

c saves 10 not 1, so i cant get the right information for arrays...

So the array Min stores 1000 not 100

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following

```
FILE *file;
char readBuffer[40];
int c;
file = fopen("your_file","r");
while ((c=getc(file))!= EOF)
{
    strcat(readBuffer, c);
    if( (char) c == ';')
  //this is the delimiter. Your min, max, name code goes here

}
   fclose(file);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `scanf` or `fscanf` like this:

```
scanf("(%d;%d;%[^)])",&min,&max,str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [cool, simple tutorial](http://www.ehow.com/how_6929534_read-csv-file-c.html) on how to do that.

Please note that you'll need to adapt the example a little bit, but that should not be too difficult.

Also you could try to find a library that does the job, I'm sure there are a lot of such libraries for C :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtok()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() { 
  char input[] = "100;200;first";
  char name[10];
  int min, max;

  char* result = NULL;
  char delims[] = ";";

  result = strtok(input, delims);
  // atoi() converts ascii to integer.
  min = atoi(result);
  result = strtok(NULL, delims);
  max = atoi(result);
  result = strtok(NULL, delims);
  strcpy(name, result);
  printf("Min=%d, Max=%d, Name=%s\n", min, max, name);
}
```

Output:

```
Min=100, Max=200, Name=first
```

Comment: dont u know how can i use this with long numbers ( with 13 digits) without long long type, i have to enter number and say is it in between 400000000000 and 49999999999, i found some ansvers vith long long int, but i'm not allowed to use it... any idea?