# Program which reads information from txt in structure

Tags: c, struct, text-files

hope you can help me with this, it's kinda tricky...
i have txt file which contents names and marks of peple

for an example

Carl,Johnson,123xxx123,9;

like in order: name,surname,certificate no,mark;

```
struct xxxxx
{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    char certificate No[10];
    int mark;
};
```

the problem starts when i need to read ten records from txt...

don't have clue how to duplicate struct, do i have to define it like ten times

struct xxxx sk1[ ],sk2[ ]... and so on...?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have defined a struct you can declare several variables of that type.

```
struct xxxx sk1;
struct xxxx sk2;
```

or even an array of them

```
struct xxxx sk[10];
```

To populate this structure with data from the text file you need to write some code, formatted as the input is I would think [fscanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/) would not be of much help as is.

The approach I would take is probably reading the entire the line using fscanf() then do some splitting on `','` to get the fields. The first three are plain `strcpy`, the last one would take use of `atoi`

My grasp of C input functions are not all that good as I much prefer C++ so you should perhaps look for a second opinion in this matter.

**Edit:** I found some perfectly good info on how to proceed from [your](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785860/arrays-from-txt-in-c-long-numbers) [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784679/reading-and-comparing-numbers-from-txt-file-c) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785309/how-to-make-arrays-from-txt-file-c)

Comment: yes, but i actually intrested in the way how to read information into struct from file...

Comment: @edGGars I updated the answer a bit, still maybe a new question is called for. Do some code along the lines of my suggestion, post a question include the txt file format/example, the struct definition and the parsing code as far as you get it. And someone should pick it up while I sleep.